# javascript gradual deceleration (left)

Tags: javascript

I've got a program where if the user holds the left or right arrow key, the character gradually accelerates in that direction, and eventually reaches a max speed. When the key is released, the character gradually slows down, until it stops completely.

My right arrow key is fine, but the left is broken. My left arrow key accelerates nicely but when the key is released the character just moves straight back to where it started before the left key was pressed. 
(possibly a bit further than where it started)

I do know why this is happening, but I tried to fix it (unsuccessfully) and I don't want to further stuff up my program.

Here's my code:

```
var maxSpeed = 15;
var xForce = 0;
var kingXPos = 10;
var kingYPos = 200;

var draw = function () {
  background(255, 0, 0);
  image(getImage("creatures/Winston"), kingXPos, kingYPos, 50, 50);

  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === RIGHT) {
    kingXPos = kingXPos + xForce;
    xForce = xForce + 0.1;
    if (xForce >= maxSpeed && keyIsPressed) {
      xForce = maxSpeed;
    }
  }

  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === LEFT) {
    kingXPos = kingXPos - xForce;
    xForce = xForce + 0.1;
    if (xForce <= -maxSpeed && keyIsPressed) {
      xForce = -maxSpeed;
    }
  }

  if (!keyIsPressed) {
    if (xForce > 0) {
      kingXPos = kingXPos + xForce;
      xForce = xForce - 0.1;
    }
  }
};
```

This code is broken because when I release the left key, my !keyIsPressed if statement is still true, and xForce is still getting smaller. I just don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `xForce` variable which has direction as `+/-` in some cases and does not have direction in other cases. This is the problem.

If you don't want to track the force with its direction, you should take care of `xForce` sign (whether it is greater than zero or not).

This might work:

```
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === RIGHT) {
    kingXPos = kingXPos + xForce;
    xForce = xForce + 0.1;
    if (xForce >= maxSpeed && keyIsPressed) {
      xForce = maxSpeed;
    }
  }

  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === LEFT) {
    kingXPos = kingXPos + xForce;
    xForce = xForce - 0.1;
    if (xForce <= -maxSpeed && keyIsPressed) {
      xForce = -maxSpeed;
    }
  }

  if (!keyIsPressed) {
    kingXPos = kingXPos + xForce;
    if (xForce > 0) {
      xForce = xForce - 0.1;
    } else if(xForce < 0) {
      xForce = xForce + 0.1;
    }
  }
```

**Note that with this code,** if the object is moving in a direction and you change the direction, it first slows down in that direction and then starts to move in the opposite direction.